# Convert quarterly data to monthly data

Tags: r, data.table

I got the following datatable with quarterly data:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(dates=c(as.Date("1983-03-31"), as.Date("1983-06-30"), as.Date("1983-09-30"), 
               as.Date("1983-12-31"), as.Date("1984-03-31"), as.Date("1984-06-30"),
               as.Date("1984-09-30"), as.Date("1984-12-31"), as.Date("1985-03-31"), 
               as.Date("1985-06-30"), as.Date("1985-09-30")),
       var=rnorm(11))
DT
# desired outout: (extract)
data.table(dates=c(as.Date("1983-01-31"), as.Date("1983-02-28"), as.Date("1983-03-31")),quarter=rep(as.Date("1983-03-31"),3), 
               var=rep(-0.6264538,3))
```

I would like to create a monthly dataset out of the quarterly one, by copying the respective quarterly values 3 times for the corresponding months. The corresponding months in `Date` format must be created first, as they should be used later on in the analysis. Can this be done easily with some sort of join? I only found ways to do it vice-versa, i.e. from monthly into quarterly by aggregation.

Preferably by using `datatable`. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a data.table option with some lubridate functions thrown in. Perhaps there's a more direct way, but this would probably do the job, too:

```
library(lubridate)
DT <- DT[rep(1:.N, each = 3)]
DT[, quarter := dates]
DT[, dates := {day(dates) <- 1; dates}]
DT[, dates := {month(dates) <- month(dates) - 1:(-1); dates}, by = quarter]
DT[, dates := dates -1]
```

We first replicate each row three times. Then we create a copy of the dates column for the quarters. Next, we set the date to the first day of the month. Then we subtract 1, 0, -1 months from each date and finally subrtact one day to arrive at the last day of the previous month.

```
head(DT)
#       quarter        var      dates
# 1: 1983-03-31 -0.6264538 1983-01-31
# 2: 1983-03-31 -0.6264538 1983-02-28
# 3: 1983-03-31 -0.6264538 1983-03-31
# 4: 1983-06-30  0.1836433 1983-04-30
# 5: 1983-06-30  0.1836433 1983-05-31
# 6: 1983-06-30  0.1836433 1983-06-30
```

Comment: Thanks looks fine to me. If there is a more direct solution I am interested of course as well, but I think this is great.

Answer (score 4):

You can enumerate the desired dates and do a rolling join:

```
DT[.(seq(as.IDate("1983-02-01"), as.IDate("1985-10-01"), by="month") - 1L), 
  on=.(dates), roll=-Inf]

         dates        var
 1: 1983-01-31 -0.6264538
 2: 1983-02-28 -0.6264538
 3: 1983-03-31 -0.6264538
 4: 1983-04-30  0.1836433
 5: 1983-05-31  0.1836433
 6: 1983-06-30  0.1836433
 7: 1983-07-31 -0.8356286
 8: 1983-08-31 -0.8356286
 9: 1983-09-30 -0.8356286
10: 1983-10-31  1.5952808
11: 1983-11-30  1.5952808
12: 1983-12-31  1.5952808
13: 1984-01-31  0.3295078
14: 1984-02-29  0.3295078
15: 1984-03-31  0.3295078
16: 1984-04-30 -0.8204684
17: 1984-05-31 -0.8204684
18: 1984-06-30 -0.8204684
19: 1984-07-31  0.4874291
20: 1984-08-31  0.4874291
21: 1984-09-30  0.4874291
22: 1984-10-31  0.7383247
23: 1984-11-30  0.7383247
24: 1984-12-31  0.7383247
25: 1985-01-31  0.5757814
26: 1985-02-28  0.5757814
27: 1985-03-31  0.5757814
28: 1985-04-30 -0.3053884
29: 1985-05-31 -0.3053884
30: 1985-06-30 -0.3053884
31: 1985-07-31  1.5117812
32: 1985-08-31  1.5117812
33: 1985-09-30  1.5117812
         dates        var
```

This rolls to the nearest later date, so if your original data has gaps, they'll need to be handled differently (eg, filling with NA first).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach, works perfectly fine (if there are no NAs).